# how to implement complx class and implementing arithmetic functions

Tags: c++, math

I am working on my assignment right now which wants me to implement complx class and also put in missing arithmetic operators, he gave us the addition one and im sure i have the subtraction and multiplication ones right but im messing up on the operator+ with double part, also not sure with the operator==. Very new to programming so if you see anything else wrong or could be improved please say so. here is the header

```
// Complx.h
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class complx
{     

public:
double real,
imag;       
complx( double real = 0., double imag = 0.); // constructor
complx operator+(complx); // operator+()

complx operator+(double); // operator+()with double
complx operator- (complx); // operator-()
complx operator* (complx); // operator*()

bool operator== (complx); // operator==()


//Sets private data members.
void Set(double new_real, double new_imaginary) {
real = new_real;
imag = new_imaginary;
}

//Returns the real part of the complex number.
double Real() {
return real;
}

//Returns the imaginary part of the complex number.
double Imaginary() {
return imag;
}
};

ostream &operator << ( ostream &out_file, complx number );

extern istream &operator >> ( istream &in_file, complx &number );

extern ifstream &operator >> ( ifstream &in_file, complx &number );

complx &operator + (double, complx);
complx &operator - (double, complx);
complx &operator * (double, complx);
```

my complex.cpp file

```
// Complx.cpp
#include "complx.h"
#include <iostream>

extern ifstream &operator >> ( ifstream &in_file, complx &number )
{
double re, is;
char ch;
if (in_file >> ch && ch == '('&& in_file >> re >> ch && ch == ','
&& in_file >> is >> ch && ch == ')')
number.Set(re,is);
else cerr << "Finish the input"<<endl;
return in_file;
}

ostream &operator<< ( ostream &out_file, complx number )
{
out_file << '(' << number.Real() << ',' << number.Imaginary() << ')';
return out_file;
}

// define constructor
complx::complx( double r, double i )
{
real = r; imag = i;
}

// define overloaded + (plus) operator
complx complx::operator+ (complx c)
{
complx result;
result.real = (this->real + c.real);
result.imag = (this->imag + c.imag);
return result;
}
//define overloaded double + operator
complx operator+(const double&, const complx& c)
{
complx operator+(const double&, const complx& c)
{
complx result;
result.real = (double real + c.real);
result.imag = (this->imag + c.imag);
return result;
}
// define overloaded - operator
complx complx::operator- (complx c)
{
complx result;
result.real = (this->real - c.real);
result.imag = (this->imag - c.imag);
return result;
}
//define overloaded * operator
complx complx::operator* (complx c)
{
complx result;
result.real = (this->real * c.real);
result.imag = (this->imag * c.imag);
return result;
}
```

and my call_complx.cpp

```
//call_complx.cpp
#include "complx.h"
ifstream infile ("in.dat");
int main()
{
          int i=0;
          complx in[7];
          double d = 4.5; 
          cout<< "The input numbers are: " << endl;

          while (infile  >> in[i]){
              cout << in[i] << endl;
              i++;
          }        
          complx s1 =  in[0] + in[1]; // calls complx::operator+()
          complx s2 =  d + in[2]; // overload operator+()
          complx s3 =  in[3] + d; // overload operator+()
          complx a = in[4] - in[5];
          complx mm=in[3]*in[4];
          complx dm=d*in[4] ;
          complx b=d-in[0] ;

          cout << "The sum is a complex number " << s1 <<endl;
          cout << "The sum is a complex number " << s2 <<endl;
          cout << "The sum is a complex number " << s3 <<endl;
          cout << "The subtract is a complex number " << a <<endl;
          cout << "The product is a complex number " << mm <<endl;          
          cout << "The subtract is a complex number " << b <<endl;
          cout << "The product is a complex number " << dm <<endl;
          if (in[4] == in[5]) cout << "in[4] and in[5] are the same " << endl;
          system("pause");
          return 0;   //successful termination
}
```

this is also my first time posting here so if theres any rules and such that im not following, please pardon and enlighten my ignorance please.

Comment: Interesting academic exercise, and considerably more in-depth than my approach which would be one line: [`#include <complex>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/complex). (but I bet you can get some interesting insights in to implementation algorithms by taking at look at that). That said, unless you have a *specific* problem, you may be better to post your source *verbatim* on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Or be more detailed in the problem description. "Messing up", while descriptive, isn't exactly informative. How is it "messing up" etc.

Comment: @WhozCraig I heard this approach is bugfree (modulo bugs!) and fast, 10/10.

Comment: sorry for not being more descriptive. i get the errors "expected primary-expression before "double" and "expected ')' before "double"" at    result.real = (double real + c.real);     on complx.cpp

Comment: See Dietmar's answer, it has some identification with the problems you're having, as well as solid suggestions on implementing your operators.

Answer (score 1):

I spotted some repeated declarations for `operatr+ (double, complx)` in your code which doesn't seem right. That is, you duplicate the declaration of the operator. Remove one copy:

```
complx operator+(const double&, const complx& c)
{
complx operator+(const double&, const complx& c) // <--- needs to go
{                                                // <--- needs to go
```

Ignoring that marginal detail, here are a few notes:

1. Generally you don't want to implement the binary arithmetic operators as members. Instead, you want to implement mutating operator using, `e.g.`, `operator+=()`, `operator-=()`, etc. and then implement the operators in terms of these, e.g.,

   ```
   complx& complx::operator+= (complx other) {
       this->real += other.real;
       this->imag += other.imag;
   } 
   complx operator+ (complx c0, complx c1) {
       return c0 += c1;
   }
   ```
2. Your multiplication is definitely wrong: According to your implmenetation *i<sup>2</sup> == i* but it should be *-1*. For the multiplication (and division) it is definitely not sufficient to do memberwise operations. Instead, the result is *(a + bi) (c + di) == (ac - bd) + (ad + bc)i* which is of course more ore less the normal distributivity applies with observing that *i<sup>2</sup> == -1*.

The neat aspect of using non-member binary operators with classes supporting implicit conversions is that you don't need to be bothered at all about the mixed type version: the implicit conversions play nicely with these operators. Of course, you can still implement the mixed type operators but you are probably best off to implement the logic just once and delegate to an already implemented operator, e.g.:

```
complx operator+ (double d, complx c) {
    return complx(d) + c;
    // or: return complx(d) += c;
}
```

BTW, you *never* want to pass built-in type by `const&`! Passing them by value can be more efficient.

Comment: +1 Outstanding answer, particularly the note on operator stacking, which or *functional* operators like these is a solid approach. Really a great set of suggestions (and of course the fixes too).